# is it possible Pattern ping in windows?

Tags: windows, networking, ping

Is it possible to *pattern ping* in Windows, like we do in linux (`ping -p ff [dest_ip]`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually **yes**, you can. The *catch* though is you have to write the app yourself, using .net and implement ping. The good news is all you have to do is copy the example [on this MS page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63bsyf0.aspx) into visual studio C#, which is free.

Comment: indeed, I've written a pinger or two into apps just to check VPN connectivity before proceeding. I thought about posting the code here, but since this is SU, not SO, i figured that might be beyond the scope of the ops question. OP, if you have the wherewithall, rolling your own is a good way to get what you want. just replace "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" with a Hex string of your choice, preferably in 32-byte format. the data field width is arbitrary, but there may be implementation restrictions on a given platform.

Answer (score 0):

No, the windows ping implementation does not include a -p option or any other option that allows you to set the payload (IIRC, the windows ping payload is the latin alphabet starting from m -thru- l).

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ping /?

Usage: ping [-t] [-a] [-n count] [-l size] [-f] [-i TTL] [-v TOS]
            [-r count] [-s count] [[-j host-list] | [-k host-list]]
            [-w timeout] [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name

Options:
    -t             Ping the specified host until stopped.
                   To see statistics and continue - type Control-Break;
                   To stop - type Control-C.
    -a             Resolve addresses to hostnames.
    -n count       Number of echo requests to send.
    -l size        Send buffer size.
    -f             Set Don't Fragment flag in packet (IPv4-only).
    -i TTL         Time To Live.
    -v TOS         Type Of Service (IPv4-only. This setting has been deprecated
                   and has no effect on the type of service field in the IP Header).
    -r count       Record route for count hops (IPv4-only).
    -s count       Timestamp for count hops (IPv4-only).
    -j host-list   Loose source route along host-list (IPv4-only).
    -k host-list   Strict source route along host-list (IPv4-only).
    -w timeout     Timeout in milliseconds to wait for each reply.
    -R             Use routing header to test reverse route also (IPv6-only).
    -S srcaddr     Source address to use.
    -4             Force using IPv4.
    -6             Force using IPv6.
```